# Eliminar duplicados en lista enlazada simple

Tags: java, lista

Intento eliminar duplicados en un lista simple con el siguiente codigo:

```
    public void eliminarRepetidos(){
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return;

        for(Nodo<T> n = this.cab; n!=null; n=n.getSiguiente()){
            for(Nodo<T> m = n.getSiguiente(); m!=null; m=m.getSiguiente()){
                if(n.getInfo() == m.getInfo()){
                    eliminar(m);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void eliminar(Nodo<T> m){
        Nodo<T> aux =this.cab;
        while(aux.getSiguiente()!= m){
            aux = aux.getSiguiente();
        }
        aux.setSiguiente(m.getSiguiente());
        m.setSiguiente(null);
        this.tam--;
    }
```

Si la lista esta vacia no se ejecutara nada.if(isEmpty())
Si la lista tiene elementos entonces procedo a eliminar tomando como referencia el nodo cabeza que en este caso seria el nodo n que esta en el primer for.
el nodo m se posicionara siempre adelante del nodo n (Segundo for), m iterara buscando coincidencias y si encuentra alguna se eliminara dicho nodo(m), osea eliminar(m);.

Al entrar al metodo eliminar(Nodo m) lo que hago es crear un nodo auxiliar(Nodo aux) y este iterara hasta ser el anterior al nodo m pasado por parametro, esto con el fin de no perder la continuidad de la lista.

Al momento de probarlo ingreso a la lista datos de tipo Integer: 
1->1->1->1->1->1->1->1->1->1->null

Deberia darme como respuesta 1->null.

Pero no los elimina todos, la salida es la siguiente:
1->1->1->1->1->null

He intentado un tiempo y no logro eliminarlos todos, ¿en que estoy fallando? o ¿que debo corregir para que el codigo funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías proporcionar cómo has implementado la clase `Nodo`.

Supongamos que el método `getInfo()` devuelva un objeto cualquiera, diferente a un atributo primitivo. Lo que sucede es que al comparar ambos objetos con `==`, estás comparando la localización a nivel de memoria de dichos objetos, por lo que puede suceder que el `-1` puede estar repetido en varias localizaciones, razón por la que, aparentemente, no los elimina todos. Lo que debes hacer es sobreescribir el método `equals(Object)` en tu clase Nodo.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Nodo)) {
        return false;
    }
    // Aquí haces comparativa de los atributos de Nodo
}
```

E invocar dicho método en tu comparación dentro del ciclo for, quedando el ciclo así:

```
    for(Nodo<T> n = this.cab; n!=null; n=n.getSiguiente()){
        for(Nodo<T> m = n.getSiguiente(); m!=null; m=m.getSiguiente()){
            if(n.getInfo().equals(m.getInfo())){
                eliminar(m);
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero esta información sirva.